# can u help me construct with this similar code but added with requirement(correct date format and it must age 18+) Java GUI

Tags: java, user-interface

private void emailKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
Boolean at=false;
Boolean dotcom=false;

```
    for(int x=1; x<=email.getText().length();x++){
    if(email.getText().substring(x-1,x).equals("@") && x>3){
        at=true;
      }
    else{
         elabel.setForeground(Color.red);
         elabel.setText("Bad Email");
    }
   
    if(x>5 && email.getText().substring(x-4,x).equals(".com") && x>3){
   dotcom=true;
      }
    else{
         elabel.setForeground(Color.red);
         elabel.setText("Bad Email");
    }
    if(at==true && dotcom==true){
        elabel.setForeground(Color.blue);
        elabel.setText("Good Email");
    }
    }
```

i want my code to show message dialog at(mm/dd/yy) label an "incorrect date format or "not 18" and "18+"

Comment: Emily, see other Emily's question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65786009/string-out-of-bounds-exception-for-for-loop

Comment: Don't use a `KeyListener`, if you have to, use a `DocumentListener` or a `ActionListener` and `FocusListener`

Answer (score 0):

I created a function that's chek years by date of bearth (with `Calendar` class).
When you run the main you should enter your date of berth and the computer will print if you're older or younger than 18.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Year:")));
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Month:")) - 1);
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Day:")));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                "Your date of bearth is " + 
        c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "\\" + (c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "\\" + c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        if (validate(c, 18)) {
            System.out.println("you\'re older then 18");
        }else {
            System.out.println("you\'re younger then 18");
        }
    }
    public static boolean validate(Calendar bearth, int yearsDiff) {
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        if (today.get(Calendar.YEAR) - yearsDiff > bearth.get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
            return true;
        }
        if (today.get(Calendar.YEAR) - yearsDiff < bearth.get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) >= bearth.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). May also use `DateTimeFormatter` and `ChronoUnit` from the same API.